# Ошибка "Command failed" в юнит-тестах на Jest для Angular

Tags: javascript, angular2, юнит-тесты, angular4

Пытаюсь настроить и запустить юнит-тестирование `Angular` с помощью `Jest`, но что-то не очень понимаю что конкретно нужно сделать. После прочтения кучи инфы и применения метода тыка вот что получилось:
**`package.json`**

```
"dependencies": {
    ...
    "@types/jest": "^22.2.3",
    "ts-jest": "^22.4.4",
    ...
},
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "^21.2.0",
    "jest": "^21.2.1",
    "jest-cli": "^21.2.1",
    ...
},
"scripts": {
    "test": "jest",
    ...
},
"jest": {
  "verbose": true,
  "globals": {
    "__TRANSFORM_HTML__": true,
    "ts-jest": {
      "enableTsDiagnostics": true
    }
  },
  "moduleDirectories": [
    "node_modules",
    "<rootDir>"
  ],
  "moduleFileExtensions": [
    "ts",
    "tsx",
    "js",
    "jsx",
    "json",
    "node"
  ],
  "transform": {
    "^.+\\.jsx$": "babel-jest",
    "^.+\\.js$": "babel-jest",
    "^.+\\.(ts?|tsx?|html)$": "ts-jest"
  },
  "testRegex": "/__tests__/.*\\.(ts|tsx|js)$",
  "testPathIgnorePatterns": [
    "config"
  ]
},
```

**`pricing.component.ts`**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-pricing',
  template: '<div>{{ hi }}</div>',
})
export class PricingComponent implements OnInit {
  hi: string;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.hi = 'Hello';
  }
}
```

**`pricing-test.ts`**

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { PricingComponent } from '../pricing.component';

describe('PricingComponent', () => {
  let component: PricingComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<PricingComponent>;


  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [PricingComponent]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
      fixture = TestBed.createComponent(PricingComponent);
      component = fixture.componentInstance;
      fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create the comp', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

При запуске команды `yarn test` в терминале, получаю вот такую ошибку: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что сделать-то нужно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В точке входа ваших тестов нужно добавить импорт зависимостей.

Примерно это выглядит как-то так:

```
import 'zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone';
import 'zone.js/dist/proxy.js';
import 'zone.js/dist/sync-test';
import 'zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch';
import 'zone.js/dist/async-test';
import 'zone.js/dist/fake-async-test';
```

Возможно, ваш тест-фреймворк позволяет добавить список зависимостей в файл конфигурации.

Обратите внимание на пакет [jest-preset-angular](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-preset-angular).
Среди прочих, он добавляет пакет [jest-zone-patch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-zone-patch).

Comment: Спасибо! Разобрался.